# Raspberry - python3.4 - socket only works from IDLE (doesnt work from terminal or autorun)

Tags: python, linux, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry-pi python3.4 script that is sending commands via socket.

The script works perfectly when running via IDLE.

It is also working when I use this in terminal (opens up IDLE and runs the script):

```
sudo idle-python3.4 -r /home/pi/off.py
```

However, it does not work when I run:

```
sudo python3.4 /home/pi/off.py
```

I need to run this program on boot and neither of the above work if I put them in `/etc/rc.local`.

The part of the code is below:

```
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.sock_STREAM)
    sock.connect(('xxx.xxx.xx.xx', xxx))
    req = struct.pack('12B', 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x01, 0, Ref,  0x00, 0x00)
    sock.send(req)
except:
    print("Error1")
finally:
    sock.close()
```

Any ideas or guidance?

Thank you!

Mike

Comment: I recommend that you change your code to display the actual error and not just "Error1". This way you would have more information for debugging the problem (which you then should include into the question).